# What are "resources" folders in SBT projects for?

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT project folders hierarchy I am to put my Scala sources in src/main/scala and tests in src/tests/scala. What am I meant to put into src/main/resources and src/tests/resources?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get a resource within scalatest w/ sbt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285898/how-to-get-a-resource-within-scalatest-w-sbt)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everything in that directory gets packed into the .jar created when you call `package`.

This means you can use it for images, sound files, text, anything that's not code but is used by your code.

Comment: Thank you, Dylan. Can you link to a Scala (2.8) code example on how do I employ these resources then?

Comment: This duplicate question has a concise example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285898/how-to-get-a-resource-within-scalatest-w-sbt

Answer (score 8):

Here's an example of copying a text file stored in resource to a local file system:

```
  def copyFileFromResource(source: String, dest: File) {
    val in = getClass.getResourceAsStream(source)
    val reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(in))
    val out = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.FileWriter(dest))
    var line: Option[String] = None
    line = Option[String](reader.readLine)
    while (line != None) {
      line foreach { out.println }
      line = Option[String](reader.readLine)
    }
    in.close
    out.flush
  }
```

Comment: What am I meant to put as "source" argument here? A short name of a file in src/main/resources? I'd like to print a short built-in help file in case a program of mine is called without parameters. So,  I've copied your function body, removed dest/out to use just println to print to stdout and used "help.txt" as source. And this gives me a NullPointerException in java.io.Reader.<init>.

Comment: See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: I think this can be shortened using `reader = io.Source.fromInputStream(in).getLines()`, `out = new PrintWriter(dest))`, then all you need is `reader foreach out.println`