# How to access test resources in Scala?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a file `data.xml` in `src/test/resources/`.

How can I read that file into a new `FileReader` in my test `data.scala` in `src/test/scala/`?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Resources are meant to be accessed using the special `getResource` style methods that Java provides. Given your example of `data.xml` being in `$SBT_PROJECT_HOME/src/test/resources/`, you can access it in a test like so:

```
import scala.io.Source

// The string argument given to getResource is a path relative to
// the resources directory.
val source = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/data.xml"))
```

Of course that `source` is now just a normal Scala IO object so you can do anything you want with it, like reading the contents and using it for test data.

There are other methods to get the resource as well (for example as a stream). For more information look at the `getResource` methods on the [Java Docs: Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: I had to add a `getClassLoader` to the instruction. The result was `Source.fromURL(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("simulation.json"))`

Comment: Confirmed Moebius comment `getClassLoader` is needed. Without it the path includes the class hierarchy directory of the test class. Something like  `~/lighthouse/target/scala-2.12/test-classes/com/mycompany/myapp/module1/utils/blabla/`. Using `getClass.getClassLoader.getResource()` the portion `com/mycompany/myapp/module1/utils/blabla/` is removed

Comment: Wasn't the case for me with class hierarchy, but with getClassLoader a slash in resource name is not needed, while without getClassLoader it is. If not used that way I"d always get a null(resource not found).

Answer (score 40):

Another alternative (especially if you need to access resource as a `File`); is to obtain it's path via:

```
val path = getClass.getResource("/testData.txt").getPath
val file = new File(path)
```

as has been pointed out in [Scala get file path of file in resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831768/scala-get-file-path-of-file-in-resources-folder)

Answer (score 27):

sbt copies files from `src/test/resources` to `target/scala-[scalaVersion]/test-classes`.

You can access the resources in your tests as follows:

```
Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/testData.txt"))
```

It does assume that `testData.txt` was directly under the folder `src/test/resources`. Add any subdirectories, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

And in cases where `getClass.getResource` does not work (don't know nor care when or why exactly), `com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource` from Google Guava usually does

```
testCompile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
```

Answer (score -5):

To know where you are in file system during test, you can do something like this in a dummy test:

```
 import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
  for(file <- new File(".").listFiles ){
   println(file.getAbsolutePath)
  }
```

Then, when you know your path, in your test you can use it as:

```
new File("./src/test/resources/yourfile.xml")
```

Comment: The files under `src/test/resources` are in test's CLASSPATH so tests can access it without the code being aware of the build directory structure.

Comment: This might be useful though, if one needs to enumerate resources (i.e. the code does not have their names fixed, but will use any files placed under there).

Comment: @akauppi this can be done with http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

Comment: this will get you in trouble when you deploy your app as a fat jar