# Read property file under classpath using scala

Tags: scala, classpath

I am trying to read a property file from classpath using scala. But it looks like it won't work, it is different from java. The following 2 code snippet, one is java (working), another is scala (not working). I don't understand what is the difference.

```
// working
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
Test.class.getResourceAsStream("conf/fp.properties")));

// not working 
val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
getClass.getResourceAsStream("conf/fp.properties")));

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
at com.ebay.searchscience.searchmetrics.fp.conf.FPConf$.main(FPConf.scala:31)
at com.ebay.searchscience.searchmetrics.fp.conf.FPConf.main(FPConf.scala)
```

Comment: Why don't you use [Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)?

Comment: Got the solution, I should use absolute path here "/conf/fp.properties", but still not clear about why the relative path work in java but not in scala

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am guessing that your `BufferedReader` is a `java.io.BufferedReader`

In that case you could simply do the following:

```
import scala.io.Source.fromUrl
val reader = fromURL(getClass.getResource("conf/fp.properties")).bufferedReader()
```

However, this leaves the question open as to what you are planning to do with the `reader` afterwards. `scala.io.Source` already has some useful methods that might make lots of your code superfluous .. [see ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source)

Comment: What if property file reside inside jar file (e.g. in resources dir)?

Comment: [From](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285898/how-to-get-a-resource-within-scalatest-w-sbt): `val source = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/conf/fp.properties"))`

Comment: that's way better approach

Comment: Thanks, but it still not working, the same exception. I don't know why here it could not locate the file.

Answer (score 10):

This code finally worked for me:

```
import java.util.Properties
import scala.io.Source

// ... somewhere inside module.

var properties : Properties = null

val url = getClass.getResource("/my.properties")
if (url != null) {
    val source = Source.fromURL(url)

    properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(source.bufferedReader())
}
```

And now you have plain old java.util.Properties to handle what my legacy code actually needed to receive.

Comment: as in [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-)
** "The specified stream remains open after this method returns. " **
So you need to assign it a tmp var, then need to call close on that so the File descriptor is not leaked:  `val reader = source.bufferedReader()`
    `properties.load(reader)`
    `reader.close()`

Answer (score 3):

My prefered solution is with [com.typesafe.scala-logging](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j_2.11). I did put an application.conf file in main\resources folder, with content like:

`services {
    mongo-db {
        retrieve = """http://xxxxxxxxxxxx""",
        base =   """http://xxxxxx"""
    }
}`

and the to use it in a class, first load the config factory from typesafe and then just use it.

`val conf = com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.load()
conf.getString("services.mongo-db.base"))`

Hope it helps!

Ps. I bet that every file on resources with .conf as extension will be read.

Answer (score 2):

For reading a Properties file i'd recommend to use `java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("conf/fp")`, it makes life a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

The NullPointerException you are seeing is caused by a bug in the underlying Java code. It *could* be caused by a mistyped file name.

Sometimes you get this error also if you're trying to load the resource with the wrong classloader.

1. Check the resource url carefully against your classpath.
2. Try `Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(...))`
3. Try `Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream())`
4. Maybe you are using other classloaders you can try?

The same story goes for `Source.fromUrl(...)`

If you're trying to load configuration files and you control their format, you should have a look at Typesafe's [Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) utility.

Answer (score 0):

The Null Pointer Exception you are getting is from getResourceAsStream returning null.   The following junit.scala snippet shows how there is a difference in class vs classloader. see [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608795/154461).  Here I assume `fileName` is the name of a file residing in the class path, but not a file next to the class running the test.

```
assertTrue(getClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName) != null)
assertTrue(getClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName) == null)
assertTrue(getClass.getResourceAsStream(fileName) == null)
assertTrue(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName) != null)
```