# Scala get file path of file in resources folder

Tags: scala, io, filepath, stanford-nlp

I am using the Stanford CRFClassifier and in order to run, it requires a file that is the trained classifier model.  I have put this file in the resources directory.  From the Javadocs for the CRFClassifier [http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.html#getClassifier(java.lang.String)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/crf/CRFClassifier.html#getClassifier%28java.lang.String%29)
the path to the file must be an input to CRFClassifier.getClassifier() and it is a java.lang.String object.  So my question is how do I tell .getClassifier() that the file is in the resources directory? i.e. how do I get the file path of a file in the resources directory?

I have tried simply

```
val classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier("./src/main/resources/my_model.ser.gz")
```

But this returns a FileNotFoundException.

I have also tried

```
Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/my_model.ser.gz"))
```

which returns a BufferedSource object, but I do not know how to get a file path from this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would this `CRFClassifier.getClassifier(getClass.getResource("/split0-ner-model.ser.gz").getPath)` work for you?

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

I managed to be able to get the file path by doing the following

`val url=getClass.getResource("/my_model.ser.gz")`

`val classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifier(url.getPath())`